# TypeScript Type Assertion in JSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jsx

How can I assert that the profile is UserProfileForAdmin type only inside the `isAdmin` JSX area to display the phone number only for the admins.

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

interface Profile {
  name: string;
}

interface UserProfileForAdmin extends Profile {
  phone: string;
}

export interface HomeSingleProfileProps {
  profile: Profile | UserProfileForAdmin;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}

const SingleProfile = (props: HomeSingleProfileProps) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {props.isAdmin ? (
          <>
            {props.profile.phone}
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            {props.profile.name}
          </>
        )}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SingleProfile;
```

[image]

Currently it gives the error

> TS2339: Property 'phone' does not exist on type 'Profile | UserProfileForAdmin'.   Property 'phone' does not exist on type 'Profile'.

**Edit:**
Is there any solution to assert the type from the following code?

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

interface Profile {
  name: string;
}

interface UserProfileForAdmin extends Profile {
  phone: string;
}

export interface HomeSingleProfileProps {
  profile: Profile | UserProfileForAdmin;
}

const SingleProfile = (props: HomeSingleProfileProps) => {
  // logic to determine if the current user is admin or not
  const isAdmin = checkIfUserIsAdmin(user); // might be true or false

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {props.isAdmin ? (
          <>
            {props.profile.phone}
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            {props.profile.name}
          </>
        )}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default SingleProfile;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this type is wrong:

```
export interface HomeSingleProfileProps {
  profile: Profile | UserProfileForAdmin;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

According to that type, `isAdmin` could be `true`, and `profile` could have a type that does *not* have a `phone`.

So I'm guessing that what you want is that a `profile` can only can a `UserProfileForAdmin` if `isAdmin` is `true`. If so, then you need to show that in your types.

```
interface UserProfileProps {
  profile: Profile;
  isAdmin: false;  
}

export interface AdminProfileProps {
  profile: UserProfileForAdmin;
  isAdmin: true;
}

export type HomeSingleProfileProps = UserProfileProps | AdminProfileProps
```

Here `HomeSingleProfileProps` is now one of two possibilities. It's either an an admin with an admin profile with a `phone`, or it's not an admin and it has a profile without a `phone.

[See playground for working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4&ssl=21&ssc=74&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBqwSA7tgCpIAe8AvnAGZQQhwBEUqGAtAHYozAAbklYBuALAAoKcB4wkUeuiRwACk3rAANipxS4cPiCQAuOAGcYUWQHMJkmlJlyFStCoCq5heoiadAGLQAIIAJiCycFTyPKHmahrauvpwYAAWEDymFla29o7SkrLyispwXj6JOr5g8XqSBmBV2b7+SPYGwOZhETxmSlreogZSBVJUkLBwxa5lPbKtSTV1KU1+SWYVUIuBIeGyHdPd+31wVgCu7aNOkhPQ8DAAnmAqABLMSADKttXNy3AAXnK3m2fyYtTgAB84PMeDskMsbmhMpY4N8eDZfusdIC4AAKNa1MzvYzozEIsEQWoASkBAD5cCkODBzlAePiUgYADyEEh0zkGOBcijUfkNQUSnCE8wAOi6sLgAH4OeKJRKuWK1VrcNKZWs2nqMlkCtrBVyAPSa7W0sx4gVajX27VS8Gy-VJGVGJAm01Cy1OgzUn3q80imBW7nm3nEK3U-L2caUSbwUJIJTnLTwMlYtqiIA)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer.
Question is:
If we determine the `isAdmin` inside the function and do not take it from params; then is it possible to Assert the Type as `UserProfileForAdmin` to get rid of this TypeScript error?

Comment: If you want a function to detect and declare an object as a type, that's a type predicate: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates. Maybe something like`const checkIfUserIsAdmin = (user: User): user is Admin => user.isAdmin`